# Do groups contain a left or a right zero?

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

I think it is impossible for a group to contain just a left or a right zero, because it would violate the identity property, but I am unable to put it into words. Could someone help out?

Comment: The element which you call zero is also sometimes called an "absorbing element", or "annihilating element". See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_element).

Comment: Could you define what you mean by a left zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $G$ has a left zero $z$ then $zg=z$ for all $g\in G$. Cancelling the $z$, one gets $g=e$ is the identity for all $g\in G$, so $G=\{e\}$.

Comment: (+1) Another way of stating this fact is: if $M$ is a nontrivial monoid with a left zero, then $M$ cannot be a group (of course, the corresponding statement for right zeroes is also true). Thus, for instance, a nontrivial ring is never a group under multiplication.